# Tablet Android gt7800 with Scanner Barcode integrated - focus input

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web, barcode-scanner

I'm working in a project where I need a barcode reader. I have an android tablet gt7800 which has a scanner barcode integrated. It works perfectly, but I always need to **focus an input to write**.

I'm okey with that and it's obvious, but the people who will use it they will not realize that they have to focus the input, and they'll think that it's not working.

The tablet has a 'plugin' for work (don't know the name, sorry) and has a button movable in all 'screens' (wherever you look at the tablet) which you press and runs the front scanner.

So, my question is: If there any way to **catch the click event** of that button of the tablet with **javascript or jquery**? Or perhaps I'd have to create an android app in native code?

PS: Sorry for my English, I'll be happy to respond to any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanner should be working as normal keyboard, so you can try to bind to [keypress event](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) on $("body") element.